# Which is more efficient: to use object as class attribute? Or to reinitialize when needed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm building a spider / scraper with Scrapy and was wondering which would be more efficient: to initialize an API wrapper object once as a class attribute? Or reinitialize with each URL request? I'm wondering in the context of overall efficiency and memory (leaks) as this will be a fairly large project (millions of requests).

**Case 1**:

```
# init API wrapper ONCE as class attribute
class ScrapySpider():

    api = SomeAPIWrapper()

    urls = [
        'https://website.com',
        # ... +1mil URLs
    ]

    def request(self):
        for url in urls:
            yield Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield self.api.get_meta(response.url)
```

**Case 2**:

```
# init new API wrapper on EACH request
class ScrapySpider():

    urls = [
        'https://website.com',
        # ... +1mil URLs
    ]

    def request(self):
        for url in urls:
            yield Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        api = SomeAPIWrapper()
        yield api.get_meta(response.url)
```

Comment: The truth is, scrapy is intended to abstract the complexity of Twisted from beginner Python programmers who will never understand it (that's ok, many expert Python programmers never will either). It's not intended for millions of requests. I wish you good luck, though.

Comment: @pguardiario I thought that Scrapy was the go-to scraping framework for scalable spiders? Is there something I should be using instead?

Comment: Initialising a class should generally be less costly than network communication. You should not worry about such micro-optimisations unless profiling shows it to be a significant performance issue.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yea I realize that it might not make that much of a difference but I just wanted to make sure that it is indeed a micro-optimization as I still don't completely understand memory management or its respective issues with scaling. And, I obviously don't want to make millions of calls to a website or it's API more times than I need to and debugging memory leaks is my personal hell. Thanks for the insight/help though! Much appreciated :)

Comment: Most Python programmers won't want to look too deeply into Twisted or Asynchio and that's where scrapy comes in. It's concurrent python scraping for dummies. If you want to dive deep I recommend an asynchronous language like JS or Go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no generic, one-size-fits-all answer to this question - it depends on how costly the object's instantiation is, how often you end up instanciating it in best / average / worst case, and, with your example using a class attribute (instead of an instance attribute), whether it's safe to share this object amongst all instances of the host class.

Note that there are two other terms to the alternative:

1/ a per-instance attribute created in the initializer:

```
class ScrapySpider():

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.api = SomeAPIWrapper()
```

which avoids the concurrent access issues you might get with a class attribute, and

2/ a cached property

```
class ScrapySpider():

    @property
    def api(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_cached_api"):
            self._cached_api = ApiWrapper()
        return self._cached_api
```

which also prevents creating the ApiWrapper instance before it's needed (might be useful if creating it is costly and it's not always needed) but adds a small overhead on attribute access.

Answer (score 2):

In the example code, using a class attribute (Case 1) should be more efficient.

Comment: At least if sharing the same SomeAPIWrapper instances between all ScrapySpider instances is safe...